# An inconsistency in Secrets of Sulphur Springs?

Tags: secrets-of-sulphur-springs

Season three premiered March 24, 2023, with the episodes "Time Won't Let Me" and "Time in a Crystal".

And in one of them, probably "Time in a Crystal", Zoey, Wyatt, and Topher are talking about Savannah's ghost, and Bennett tells them they know that Savannah didn't die and thus isn't a ghost.

I don't remember Bennett ever learning that Savannah didn't die.  Griffin and Harper have kept their adventures and discoveries secret from their parents.  And in  "Time Won't Let Me" the living Savannah was hiding so that Bennett wouldn't see her.

So am I forgetting about a plot where Bennett somehow learned that Savannah didn't die while not learning about all the time travel?

Comment: should a tag referencing "inconsistencies" in sci fi media be added? there's nothing wrong with plot fails and it may be of interest to highlight them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Season one towards the end, Savannah left a note in the coffee can by the treehouse to show Ben she was alive and well so he could be relieved of his guilt and so Savannah didn’t have to leave her family in 1962.

Comment: This was after Griffin and Harper went back to find Savannah and ask her to come back with them to solve their problems with their parents, and Savannah had the idea to use the coffee can so she didn’t have to leave.